# Migrating outlook 2007 addin to outlook 2013

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010, outlook-2007

I have developed add-in for outlook 2007.
I need to adjust the add-in code to outlook 2013, is there any migration tool / any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is very little you would actually need to change. Your Outlook 2007 Object Model code should work the same in 2013.

The main thing you would need to change is your Outlook 2007 code that adds buttons to the Toolbar (CommandBar), so that it displays buttons in the Outlook 2013 Ribbon. See the [Ribbon Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386097.aspx) page on MSDN for more info.